# Display global recent posts

Tags: magento, fishpig

I've installed the plugin out of the box - with no configuration, and the recent posts show recent posts from the category you are in, not all categories.

How can this be amended to show recent posts from all visible categories regardless of the blog page you are on?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this into any CMS block
{{widget type="wordpress/sidebar_widget_posts" title="Recent Posts" number="5" template="wordpress/sidebar/widget/posts.phtml"}}

and show this cms block on any side bar of your site